# Application updated version : Server initiated

Tags: android, java-me

Can this be solution for Server initiated mobile application update. We are gonna build our own distribution system for mobile apps. What we want to achieve that if for any application new version is uploaded ... that can be sent to user device and the application can be installed in the device.

Proposed Solution :

As of now solution is proposed for J2ME devices but on later date little tweaks in the solution can also allow it to be implemented for Symbian and BB Devices also.

As soon as there's an application update at server side .. the server sends an sms containing the link to download (JAD file ) the new version of same application. Now this incoming sms will be trapped at the mobile device by the applicaton. the application  will be shut down and this link will be opened up in browser. The link will automatically download the application and install the application in mobile device.

Comment: Your this headache is already solved by Android market

Comment: Thanks Saurabh.. I uncovered this solution after looking at android market how  user can send and installs the application from web server . Is it a right approach when targeting J2ME Symbian or BB devices...

Comment: Its been a long time I worked on either of platforms you mentioned but as much I remember the method you asked in question is followed by J2ME and BB not android so no problem using for them